# Send gMail with Perl

Tags: perl, gmail

Despite substantial research and many posts that seem to indicate this isn't too tough, I'm at a loss as to how to send a gMail through Google without the need to connect via SMTP. I've successfully implemented code that polls and posts Google Docs. I would think this would be easier.

Several posts indicate that Email::Send::Gmail is the way to go, but that module is not available via PPM (with all default repositories added).

Could someone please let me know if I'm on the right track?

I apologize for a lack of details, but I'm not sure I know what the exact problem is, so before I post tons of likely irrelevant information, could someone please verify for me that they have successfully implemented the Email::Send::Gmail module and provide an example if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, then I'd recommend using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and then installing [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33/lib/Email/Send/Gmail.pm) via CPAN.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That seems to be the consensus, but I can't figure out how to get it installed. I've attempted to sort out the confusion of installing a mod that isn't available on PPM, but that got me nowhere. How did you install that mod?

Comment: Once you have Strawberry Perl installed (and have it set in your path as the default Perl installation), then fire up the command prompt and enter `cpan install Email::Send::Gmail`, and CPAN should work its magic from there.  Depending on how the system is set up, you might want to make sure that you run `cmd.exe` as an administrator (to make sure you have all the necessary write privileges, etc).

Comment: You don't need Strawberry Perl. Just type in `cpan Email::Send::Gmail` (no "install") whether you have ActivePerl, Strawberry Perl or cygwin's `perl`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to install Strawberry Perl. You can use [ActivePerl with the CPAN archive](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl). However to do that, you have to do a bit of legwork first:

- Go to ActiveState's Perl Package Manager and install the *CPAN* package.
- Once the package is installed, open a console window and run `cpan` from the command line. The `cpan` process will detect that you don't have the MinGW compiler environment installed, and will install it.

Now that you have cpan working, you need to update it to the latest version of CPAN.

- At the `cpan>` prompt (if you quit out of CPAN already, restart it), run `install CPAN`. This will load in the latest copy of the cpan utility.
- When you get the `cpan` prompt back, run `reload`.

Now that CPAN is working and updated, you get to install the `Email::Send::Gmail` package:

- At the `cpan>` prompt, type in `install Email::Send::Gmail`. It might have to install some prerequisites. Basically answer *yes* to whatever CPAN asks, and you'll be all right.

I just did this myself to verify it works.